# Clojure Data Structure Functions

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and trying to learn the basics.  One thing that tripped me up is understanding the correlation between the data structures and the functions they use.

For instance, if I create a new Vector:

```
(def my-vec [1 2 3])
```

Then when I try to call `my-vec`:

```
(my-vec)
```

I get:

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

I know that I can pass an argument and it appears to be calling `get` but how do I know?  What args does `PersistentVector` take and where do I find documentation about it?

I tried:

```
(doc PersistentVector)
```

But that returns `nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation can be found under IPersistentVector here:
http://clojure.org/data_structures

In particular:
Vectors implement IFn, for invoke() of one argument, which they presume is an index and look up in themselves as if by nth, i.e. vectors are functions of their indices.

Comment: That helps!  So when I do `(my-vec)` or `(my-vec 1)` it calls `invoke()` which for `IPersistentVector` calls `nth`?

Comment: Found the answer in the code: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java#L593

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a number to a Clojure vector the vector will use that number as an index into it's self and return the value at that index:

```
user> (def my-vec [1 2 3 4 5])
#'user/my-vec
user> (my-vec 2)
3
```

this allows you to write expressions like this which grab several keys out of a vec

```
user> (map my-vec [1 3 4])
(2 4 5)
```

Comment: Hmmm I guess someone got confused with your statement 'look that number up' and that caused a down vote.. Please make it clear that the number is an index and not a value in vector

Comment: fixed :) though i suspect someone just down-voted all the answers in this question

Comment: Sorry Arthur.  I down voted this because it doesn't answer my actual question.  My question wasn't about why I was getting an error.  It was about how do I find what function is getting called.  `invoke()` is the magic piece that I didn't know about.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of a vector as mapping indexes `0, 1, 2, ..., N` to values, one at each index. Abstractly, it's a special case of a map where the keys are integers starting from 0. That notion helps to see the consistency in Clojure between maps and vectors when used as functions:

```
(<ILookup-able-collection> <key-for-lookup>)
```

JavaScript does something similar, allowing you to use `[]` syntax for lookup on arrays or objects.

Answer (score -2):

`my-vec` isn't a function, so you should call: `my-vec`  not `(my-vec)`

Try:   `(nth my-vec i)`   for get i-th element of this vector.

link: [nth](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/nth)